# How to change a variable from a command discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

this is my first post here on Stacked Overflow and I have found an answer to almost every coding problem I have had.
But I haven't found any help with this problem:
I have made a bot and I want to change a variable using a command in discord, like this: !test 1 which would then change a variable to test, this is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, variable):
  print(variable)
  await ctx.send(variable)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: You’re question is somewhat confusing: are you trying to change the value of the variable to the string value `test`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a global variable or a bot attribute and edit it

```py
# Global Var
var = None

@client.command()
async def test(ctx, variable):
  global var
  print("Before", variable)
  var = variable
  await ctx.send(var)


# Bot Attribute

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Ready")
  client.var = None

@client.command()
async def test(ctx, variable):
  print("Before", client.var)
  client.var = variable
  await ctx.send(client.var)
```

Comment: After about 5 minutes of interweaving it with my code, it worked flawlessly and you were really quick!! tysm :)